# How to get the minimum from two Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select the minimum values from two Pandas Series with the same index, how can I do that ?

```
s1 = pd.Series({'ABC': 0.2, 'XYZ': 1})
s2 = pd.Series({'ABC': 2, 'XYZ': 0.3})
```

Desired output would be :

```
ABC    0.2
XYZ    0.3
dtype: float64
```

The Series can have 2 or more rows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

```
s3 = s1.append(s2).groupby(level=0).min()
```

Comment: and with ```pd.concat([s1,s2]).groupby(level=0).min()```